# Посчитать кол-во четных чисел в ряду чисел Фибоначчи до 10000 (длина ряда Фибоначчи)

Tags: python, for, python-3.8, числа-фибоначчи

Что мне известно:

Вывод чисел ряда фибоначчи:

```
n = int(input("Введите n: "))
f1 = 0
f2 = 1
print(f1)
print(f2)
for i in range(n):
    f3 = f1 + f2
    print(f3)
    f1 = f2
    f2 = f3
```

Также то , что каждое третье число ряда является четным , пример: **0**, 1, 1, **2**, 3, 5, **8**

и то что четное число можно найти по формуле f3 = 4 * f2 + f1; Пример: **8 = 4*2 + 0** и **34 = 4 * 8 + 2** ;

Я не могу понять как вывести количество четных чисел из ряда.

Comment: А просто убрать `print(f2)` и сделать проверку перед `print(f3)` чтобы `f3` была четной вам не подходит? Так же цикл должен идти не до `n` а до `n - 2` иначе 2 лишних числа подсчитано.

Comment: Если числа нумеруются с 1 то `print((n-1) // 3)` и считать сам ряд не надо (если действительно нужно только количество)

Comment: Пожалуйста если вам помог один из трех приведенный ответов, то выберите его как "Правильный ответ" нажав на галочку слева от ответа :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Если уж надо подсчитать кол-во четных чисел, то уберите все `print`
2. Создайте переменную например `count` и изначально она должна равняться `1`, т.к. последовательность начинается с 0, и когда `f3` четное, то увеличивайте эту переменную на единицу
3. Так же нужно, чтобы цикл шел не до `n`, а до `n - 2`, т.к. 2 числа (0 и 1) уже подсчитаны.

   Пример кода:

   ```py
   n = int(input("Введите n: "))
   f1 = 0
   f2 = 1
   count = 1
   for i in range(n - 2):
       f3 = f1 + f2
       if(f3 % 2 == 0):
           count += 1
       f1 = f2
       f2 = f3

   print(count)
   ```

Или второй более простой способ найти кол-во четных чисел в последовательности, используя одну формулу.

Как писал @Mike "*Если числа нумеруются с 1, то ...*" и привел формулу `(n - 1) // 3`, но т.к. последовательность начинается с 0, то вам нужно прибавить еще `1`, то есть `(n - 1) // 3 + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Сделай переменную и увеличивай её когда число четное, потом выведи.

```
n = int(input("Введите n: "))
f1 = 0
f2 = 1
i = 0
print(f1)
print(f2)
for i in range(n):
    f3 = f1 + f2
    if f3 % 2 == 0:
        i += 1
    print(f3)
    f1 = f2
    f2 = f3
print(i)
```

Comment: При `n = 10` у вас выводится в конце `9`, что очевидно не правильно

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вы высчитываете ряд, у нас же есть закономерность по четным числам и этого вполне достаточно для получения общего количества:

```py
n = int(input("Введите n: "))
print((n + 2) // 3)
```

Comment: Это неправильная закономерность - на 7 выводит 3

Comment: а на 4  выводит 2

Comment: @FotonPC, а сколько должно выводить? Автор вопроса написал `пример: **0**, 1, 1, **2**, 3, 5, **8**` как раз 3 элемента из 7.

Comment: окей, хорошо, !